# How to set NetBeans as a default editor in FileZilla

Tags: ftp, default, netbeans, editor, filezilla

When I open any `php`, `html`, or `css` files FileZilla opens them in GEdit. Instead I would like FileZilla to open them in NetBeans 7.3. I would like to set NetBeans as the default editor in FileZilla.

Please suggest a procedure to open the files in NetBeans 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

When you right-click on a file of the type that you mention, it should give you the option to select the default program to open files of that type. If this does not help, you may wish to check the documentation for FileZilla, which can be found here:

https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 7.3 executable can be found in /usr/share/applications/NetBeans IDE 7.3

Set this as your default editor in filezilla.

Answer (score 1):

As reference from [set NetBeans as a default editor in FileZilla](http://guruquest.net/question/set-default-editor-for-filezilla-in-ubuntu/)

**Please follow below steps to set default editor in ubuntu 16.04.**

Open Filezilla

Go to Edit >> Preferences >>

Select Left Side Tab:

File Editing >> File Type Associations

set netbeans as a default editor for filezilla:

**Netbeans executable file can be found at: /usr/share/applications/NetBeans/**

```
js /usr/share/applications/NetBeans/

php /usr/share/applications/NetBeans/

html /usr/share/applications/NetBeans/

css /usr/share/applications/NetBeans/
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you can go to netbeans  Desktop icon right-click-> properties copy command and past it to FileZilla->Edit->settings->File Editing slect user
custom editor and paste command there it will work for me.